# What is the closest thing to Slime for Scheme?

Tags: emacs, lisp, scheme, common-lisp, slime

I do most of my development in Common Lisp, but there are some moments when I want to switch to Scheme (while reading *Lisp in Small Pieces*, when I want to play with continuations, or when I want to do some scripting in Gauche, for example). In such situations, my main source of discomfort is that I don't have Slime (yes, you may call me an addict).

What is Scheme's closest counterpart to Slime? Specifically, I am most interested in:

- Emacs integration (this point is obvious ;))
- Decent tab completion (ideally, c-w-c-c TAB should expand to call-with-current-continuation). It may be even symbol-table based (ie. it doesn't have to notice a function I defined in a `let` at once).
- Function argument hints in the minibuffer (if I have typed `(map |)` (cursor position is indicated by `|`)), I'd like to see `(map predicate . lists)` in the minibuffer
- Sending forms to the interpreter
- Integration with a debugger.

I have ordered the features by descending importance.

My Scheme implementations of choice are:

- MzScheme
- Ikarus
- Gauche
- Bigloo
- Chicken

It would be great if it worked at least with them.

Comment: a comment not an answer - you probably already know this- but the DrScheme IDE has emacs key bindings, tab completion(though not with tab), integrated documentation, debugger and a bunch of other tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also might consider Scheme Complete:

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/SchemeComplete

It basically provides tab-completion.

Answer (score 16):

SLIME's contrib directory seems to have SWANK implementations for MIT Scheme and Kawa.

Answer (score 11):

[Geiser](http://nongnu.org/geiser/) provides an excellent environment for Scheme. The latest version now also can interact with [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), [Chibi Scheme](https://github.com/ashinn/chibi-scheme), [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) as well as that old standby [MIT Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), in addition to [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) and [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/). I would suggest [installing it](http://nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_2.html#Installation) via [Melpa](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started), specially in order to get the latest version handling the much wider selection of REPLs.

Answer (score 7):

A commentator has said: "DrScheme IDE has emacs key bindings" and it is a highly regarded IDE with many of the features you explicitly listed.

Additionally, scheme-mode for Emacs provides some of the features from SLIME - the integrated REPL, the ability to send forms to that REPL and to load entire files.  As far as I know, there is no equivalent, in general for the scheme's you've listed, for things like connecting to a running image remotely (versus a scheme repl in an Emacs buffer), or the debugger integration.

Answer (score 7):

For my work with mzscheme i usually use cmuscheme + quack, that provide almost what i need during development.

Bigloo comes with very powerful bee-mode.

And for gauche you can use GCA package that provides names completion, display of function's descriptions & inserting of code templates

**Update**: I published [article about Scheme + Emacs integration](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsScheme.html) on my site

Answer (score 6):

Well... I would say [Slime for scheme](http://mumble.net/~campbell/slime48.html) is the closest thing to Slime for Scheme ;)

Comment: Yes, of course I've seen Slime48. However, (a) it works only with Scheme48, (b) only with an older version of Scheme 48. You've got a point, though, I should have mentioned my Scheme implementations of choice in the question (I've edited it appropriately).

Answer (score 6):

You can use Chicken Scheme with slime by using swank-chicken.

I'd suggest taking a look at [geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) mode, but it only supports Racket and Guile right now which I don't see on your list.

Comment: At this point in time, Geiser claims support for quite a bit more than just Racket and Guile: https://github.com/jaor/geiser#requirements. This is also mentioned in @haziz's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28998868/2636454.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it, but you might try [Quack](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/quack.el) with `mzscheme`.

SLIME is pretty hard to beat though.  There's a lot of niceness going on in the SWANK end of it.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a Slime backend for various Scheme's called [r7rs-swank](https://github.com/ecraven/r7rs-swank).